# Is there a cleaner way to prevent multi-click for an action calling AJAX?

Tags: angularjs

I have a view which requires ajax call to be made on a button click. While the request is being processed, I don't want requests to stack up if in case the user clicks unecessarily. In order to block multiple request made through I have made the following setup.

In view

```
<button ng-click="getBooks()"></button>
```

In Controller

```
var ajaxInProgress = false;
$scope.getBooks = function () {
  if (ajaxInProgress) {
    return false;
  }
  ajaxInProgress = true;
  BooksFactory
    .getBooks()
    .then(function (response) {
      ajaxInProgress = false;
    })
    .catch(function() {
      ajaxInProgress = false;
    });
};
```

This works pretty well for me, but adding this to the multiple such functions in the same view, the controller is starting to get messy. 
Could there be a better solution to clean up this mess ?

Comment: How does that prevent multiple clicks? The button is always enabled, and the allowAjax variable preventing the request from being sent never changes. Using finally() would make the code cleaner already.

Comment: The request is blocked on the controller level. Also, the variable is ajaxInProgress not allowAjax.
Either way, even if the ng-disabled is added to button, the code population in the controller remains the same.

Comment: Read the code you posted. The variable that blocks the request is `allowAjax`. And, as I said, disabling the button (and thus removing the useless if), in addition to using finally(), would make the code cleaner (and the user would have a visual clue of why nothing happens and learn that he must not click twice).

Comment: As you have mentioned about the code population i.e. amount of the code, it seems that you want to divide the code in multiple files as you have also stated that it works pretty well for you. Is it?

Comment: Oh my bad ! :) Didn't notice the typo while making the demo. 
And thanks, the finally block cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a scope variable and bind it to ng-disabled. This prevent the extra if at beginning of the scoped function:

In view:

```
<button ng-click="getBooks()" ng-disabled="inProgress"></button>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.inProgress = false;
$scope.getBooks = function () {
    $scope.inProgress = true;
    BooksFactory
       .getBooks()
       .then(function (response) {
           // do something with response;
       })
       .catch(function() {
           // error handling
       })
       .finally(function() {
           $scope.inProgress = false;
       })      
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the finally block helped to clean it up a bit